# How to configure Hotmail to delete emails on server?

Tags: email-client, outlook.com

I use Hotmail to pull down emails from my pop server but I cannot find a way to have hotmail delete them on the server once they are downloaded.  The result is my email box is full.  I cannot find a setting that will delete the downloaded messages from the server.  Is there a way?

Comment: Which client are you using?

Comment: @Matteo, Hotmail.

Comment: @ChiliYago, yes this was clear, not the server, the client. The email program where you configured your POP Hotmail account.

Comment: @Matteo, yes, Hotmail *is* the client. He is downloading emails from another account *to Hotmail*.

Comment: Yes Hotmail is the client in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to leave the messages on the mail server or not.

If you are setting up a new account, click *Advanced Options* in the setup page (figure 1), or if you have already created the account, then click *Edit* in the account-management page (figure 2). Then in the account *Add/Edit* page (figure 3), un-check the *Leave a copy of my messages on the server* option.

**Figure 1**: Add account page

[image]

**Figure 2**: Account-management page

[image]

**Figure 3**: Add/Edit account page

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much.  I have no idea why I could not locate that.

Comment: It took me a few minutes to even find the link to *add* another account. `:-)`